# Um, Hi I'm a Beginner and don't know how to speed my code up. My homework is to write a program for CCC '20 S2 - Escape Room faster than two seconds

Tags: java

Um, hi I'm a beginner and don't know how to speed my code up. My homework is to write a program for CCC '20 S2 - Escape Room faster than **two seconds**.
The objective is to determine if it is possible to escape from a room. The room is an M-by-N grid with each position (cell) containing a positive integer. The rows are numbered 1,2,…,M and the columns are numbered 1,2,…,N. We use (r,c) to refer to the cell in row r and column c.

You start in the top-left corner at (1,1) and exit from the bottom-right corner at (M,N). If you are in a cell containing the value x, then you can jump to any cell (a,b) satisfying a×b=x. For example, if you are in a cell containing a 6, you can jump to cell (2,3).

Note that from a cell containing a 6, there are up to four cells you can jump to: (2,3),(3,2),(1,6), or (6,1). If the room is a 5-by-6 grid, there isn't a row 6 so only the first three jumps would be possible.
Here is my Code:

```
package programs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Escape_Room {

    static boolean method(int[][] array, int m, int n, int x, int y, boolean check, ArrayList<String> list) {
        boolean flag=false;
        for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                if(array[i][j]==(x*y) && !list.contains(i+", "+j)) {
                    list.add(i+", "+j);
                    flag=true;
                    if (i==0 && j==0) {
                        check=true;
                        return check;
                    }
                    boolean o=method(array, m, n, i+1, j+1, check, list);
                    if (o==true) {
                        return o;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag==false) {
            return flag;
        }
        return check;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int m=Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        int n=Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        int[][] array=new int[m][n];
        String[] strarray=new String[m];
        for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
            strarray=input.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                array[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(strarray[j]);
            }
        }
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean o=method(array, m, n, m, n, false, list);
        if (o==true) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
        else if (o==false) {
            System.out.println("no");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is generally not possible to predetermine runtime of a program. Do you have given any complexity, variable constraints or worst test case?

Comment: ^ What @Ecto said, and also, your code seems to be incomplete.  It would help if you could post a working example, so we could give you tips on how to optimize it.

Comment: Well, currently your program takes ∞ seconds to run, because it doesn’t compile.  So change both occurrences of `method(` to `calculate(`.  (Seriously, we can’t test code that doesn’t compile.)  And I suspect changing `ArrayList` to `Set` will improve the speed considerably.

Comment: about 10 by 10 grid

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Take a look at this. I have tried grids 10x10 - solved in cca **3-4ms** (including input), which is far below 2s.

```
class Escape_Room {

    static boolean method(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> transitionMap, int size, int start) {
        Set<Integer> closed = new HashSet<Integer>(size);
        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(start);
        int key;
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            key = q.poll();
            if(closed.contains(key)) {
                continue;
            }
            if(key == size) {
                return true;
            }
            closed.add(key);
            if(transitionMap.containsKey(key)) {
                for (int i : transitionMap.get(key)) {
                    if(i == size) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (!closed.contains(i)) {
                        q.add(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}

public class Solution {
    static StringBuilder str;
    static InputStreamReader in;
    static int buf;

    private static int readInt() throws IOException {
        buf = 0;
        int c;
        do {
            c = in.read(); 
        } while (c < '0' || c > '9' );
        do {
            buf = 10*buf + c - 48;
            c = in.read();
        } while (!(c < '0' || c > '9' ));
        return buf;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        in = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
        int m=readInt();
        int n=readInt();
        int size = m*n;
        Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> transitionMap = new HashMap<>(size);
        Set<Integer> temp;
        int start = 0, key = 0;

        for (int i = 0, j, value; i < m; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                key = (i+1)*(j+1);
                value = readInt();
                if(i == 0 && j == 0) {
                    start = key;
                }
                if (transitionMap.containsKey(key)) {
                    transitionMap.get(key).add(value);
                } else {
                    temp = new HashSet<>(size);
                    temp.add(value);
                    transitionMap.put(key, temp);
                }
            }
        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();       
        boolean o = Escape_Room.method(transitionMap, size, start);
        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(o?"yes":"no");
        System.out.println("Finished in: " + (t3 - t1) + "ms. Input: " + (t2 - t1)  + "ms. Solving: " + (t3 - t2) + " ms.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

apologies that I am not so familiar with Java, but here is my C++ solution that I wrote, after some thinking.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef vector<int> vint;
typedef pair<int,int> pii;
vector<pii> vpairs[1000001];
vector<vector<bool>> vis;
int main(void){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
    int A,B;
    cin>>A>>B;
    for(int i=0;i<A;i++)
    {
        vector<bool> newvecbool;
        for(int j=0;j<B;j++)
        {
            newvecbool.push_back(false);
            int k;
            cin>>k;
            vpairs[k].push_back(pii(i,j));
        }
        vis.push_back(newvecbool);
    }
    queue<pii> queue;
    queue.push(pii(A,B));
    while(!queue.empty())
    {
        pii curpair = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        if(curpair.first==1 && curpair.second==1){
            cout<<"yes";
            return 0;
        }
        int value = curpair.first*curpair.second;
       // cout<<curpair.first<<' '<<curpair.second<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<vpairs[value].size();i++)
        {
            pii pair = vpairs[value][i];
            if(!vis[pair.first][pair.second]){
                //int fuck=pair.first-1,me=pair.second-1;
                vis[pair.first][pair.second] = true;
                queue.push(pii(pair.first+1,pair.second+1));
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"no";
}
```

This code should compile within time and should score full marks. Maximum time on single test case is 0.338 seconds on DMOJ online judge.